# Resume Salesforce Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, flow-builder

I have a custom action on Opportunity Object that calls a Screen flow. User can click on the Action and start the flow. But in the meantime, user clicks the "X" that closes the flow. Is there a chance we can invoke the previous flow when clicking that action that initiates the flow? Ideally, i would like to go to the screen i closed the previous flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user clicks the "X" that will end the flow, no possibility to resume. A couple options:

- Enable the ability for users to Pause flows. This will give you the
  option to put a Pause button on Flow Screens, then users can resume
  Flows that they've paused.
- Another alternative is to make as many updates as possible between
  screens along the way with a stage or status indicator on a record,
  and then build into the flow a way to examine the record to skip to
  the screen after the last update.

Comment: Thank you Jeff!